# Java table implementation without SQL

Tags: java, linked-list, hashtable

I am implementing the No-undo/redo algorithm of transaction. I am planning to use the built in features of Java rather than using the SQL tables. But I am not sure on how to use them to the full effect. So any help or pointer in the right direction for my implementation will be highly appreciated. My task is as below.

Whenever I get a new transaction, I have to insert it into a transaction table. Let's say I get a transaction as below.

`b1;`

So, my transaction table will be as below.

```
 TransactionID     Transaction_Status     Transaction_Items

       1                Active                   NIL
```

Now, when I receive an item to be written with the same transaction ID, I have to update the transaction_items column alone.

My received transaction item will be like below.

`W1(X,2,0);`

```
TransactionID      Transaction_Status      Transaction_Items

     1                   Active                  X
```

After I encounter a commit transaction,

`C1;`

My transaction table should be updated as below.

```
TransactionID       Transaction_Status      Transaction_Items

      1                   Commit                   X
```

I can implement the above structure using a SQL table and update the columns easily. But am planning to use the rich implementations available in java itself. I decided to implement using linked list. But I am not able to set a key in linked list. Basically, I am trying to implement an array of linked list. I am unable to understand the concept clearly. Any help in the right direction to implement the above would be highly appreciated.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

---

I am using arraylist to implement the above structure that I have discussed. The set statement overrides the value that I have set previously. By this way, I can simulate the db update operation. Suppose initially my transactionitem arraylist has the following items.

X
Y

Now I want to add another Z to X (Say X Z). I am traversing to that particular instance using the for loop with the arraylist.size as the upper limit. Once I find my particular item, I am copying the existing value to a local string. After that I am concatenating my desired value that needs to be inserted. After doing it, I am using the below line to do the actual update.

transactionitem.set(i, transactionupdate);

Thanks everyone for the help. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have been on right track with database, and by dumping it, you are going to lose a lot.

In terms of richness, it will be really hard to beat using local SQLite database to keep your objects.

Below are some issues that are very difficult to implement in Java only, but you get them for free from SQLite(+Java):

- Use arbitrary list of columns for any tabular data, and offer user to sort by any column - all you need to do is to change ORDER BY clause.
- By creating appropriate indexes, you can maintain highest performance, even if list of objects is really large.
- Use standard SQL to do your data manipulation (with indexes - very fast!).
- You can make use of real transactions that SQLite has to offer, and can *guarantee data consistency* at all times.
- If your Java app quits or worse - crashes, all your Java objects are gone. But, if you keep them in database, you simply read them from database on start and you can continue where you left off - there is no need to think about serialization or deserialization (or, at least it should be much less of an issue).
- For some situations, you don't want to keep data on disk - that's fine. Simply use SQLite in-memory database by using `:mem:` as database file name - it is very fast and very handy to do quick data manipulation using SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I can connect to the database and do my operations easily. However, I wanted to learn some complex structures in java. Is it possible to implement in java (I saw so many features such as arraylists, linkedlists, hashedlists, maps etc). However, am confused on which to use and where to start.

Comment: Sure, choice is yours. In the end, you might end up reinventing the wheel for your Java Table without SQL, something like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). But almost all the things you mentioned map into SQL pretty good, and unlike Java, are not constrained by your memory: arraylist => table, map => table with indexed unique key column, etc...